# How can install vlc 2.1.6 on ubuntu 16.04lts

Tags: vlc, video-streaming

I want to install  vlc 2.1.6 on Ubuntu16.04.Can you help me ?
The reason is explained in
[unsupported codec: mp3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037320/unsupported-codec-mp3)
. I dont have this problem When I used vlc2.1.6 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Do you need 2.1.6 or 2.1.6 or newer? In the latter case https://snapcraft.io/vlc

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 comes with VLC 2.2.2 in its official repositories. Any reason why you would need that specific older version?

Comment: @Bruni I only need version 2.1.6

Comment: @ByteCommander vlc 2.2.2  or newer on my ubuntu 16.04 unsupported  mp3 codec .

Answer (score 0):

You can find the version that you are looking for [here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.1.6/) .
Download it (vlc-2.1.6.tar.xz), extract it, enter to the extracted folder then you can install it and its plugins by typing: `make install`. You an find more information in the INSTALL file.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago, after a few failed attempts I managed to install VLC 2.1.6 on freshly installed ubuntu 16.04 (amd64). Actually I want it to be in my xenialpup64-xfce puppy linux. As you may know, VLC 2.1.6 is available from "trusty-updates" apt sources list channel. So what I did is change my `/etc/apt/sources.list` from anything "xenial" to "trusty" and do `apt update` and `apt install vlc`, installation will fail but all deb should be in `/var/cache/apt/archive/`. Alternatively you can apt download all the needed package (remove anyting after (and) underscore (_)):

```
libass4_0.10.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libavcodec54_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libavformat54_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libavutil52_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libbasicusageenvironment0_2014.01.13-1+deb8u1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libdvbpsi8_1.0.0-3_amd64.deb
libebml4_1.3.0-2+deb8u1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libenca0_1.15-2_amd64.deb
libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.6_amd64.deb
libgroupsock1_2014.01.13-1+deb8u1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
liblivemedia23_2014.01.13-1+deb8u1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libmatroska6_1.4.1-2+deb8u1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libopencore-amrwb0_0.1.3-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libopenjpeg2_1.3+dfsg-4.7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libpostproc52_6%3a0.git20120821-4_amd64.deb
libproxy-tools_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
libsidplay2_2.1.1-14_amd64.deb
libswscale2_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libusageenvironment1_2014.01.13-1+deb8u1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
libvlc5_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb
libvlccore7_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb
libvo-aacenc0_0.1.3-1_amd64.deb
libvo-amrwbenc0_0.1.3-1_amd64.deb
libvpx1_1.3.0-2_amd64.deb
libx264-142_2%3a0.142.2389+git956c8d8-2_amd64.deb
vlc_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb
vlc-data_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_all.deb
vlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb
vlc-plugin-notify_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb
vlc-plugin-pulse_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb
```

I'm on amd64 so if you are on i386 you should change those word amd64. Next I made a few modification to 2 package description: libproxy-tools_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb and vlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb:

```
mkdir libproxy-tools_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64
dpkg-deb --raw-extract libproxy-tools_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb libproxy-tools_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64/
edit libproxy-tools_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64/DEBIAN/control using text editor, replacing  libproxy1 (>= 0.4.7) to libproxy1v5 from Depends: 
dpkg-deb --build libproxy-tools_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64

mkdir vlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64
dpkg-deb --raw-extractvlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64.deb vlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64/
edit vlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64/DEBIAN/control using text editor removing "libgnutls28 (>= 3.2.10-0), " from Depends:
dpkg-deb --build vlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4_amd64 to make a modified vlc-nox deb package
```

After that we can install all dowloaded deb package using `dkpg -i`.

Comment: 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) went out of public support in April 2019. I won't recommend using the sources of other release since it might affect other packages too and may generate dependency issues with other packages too.